# How to get the attribute "href" from an "a" tag in Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am making a web-scraping project that basically fetches me images from Google Images. In order to get the image src, i use

```
Element.attr("href")
```

However, it returns

```
#
```

My Code

```
Document shivWall = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).get();
Elements smallImgElements = shivWall.getElementsByClass("rg_bx rg_di rg_el ivg-i");
smallImgElements.get(0).select("a.rg_l").get(0).attr("href");
```

I have tried numerous ways, but none of them worked. I even checked again by changing the attr argument to some random value, and it returns null as expected. But, for "href", it just returns a "#". Please help.

Comment: Can you share your HTML too ?

Answer (score 0):

If you will examine the structure of html that you get with `Document shivWall = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).get();` you will find out, that `#` is the initial value of your `href` argument. The url are added dynamically with a javascript after page is loaded. Jsoup cannot handle this.

To get urls you can use this code:

```
for(Element e : shivWall.select(".rg_meta.notranslate")) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map imageData = gson.fromJson(e.text(), Map.class);
    System.out.println(imageData.get("ou"));
}
```